# Exposing Variables in addon OR opening file through addon

Tags: python, add-on

I wrote a script, which imports a .stl file and does stuff with it.
Now I want to convert the script into an addon.

Currently the file and directory are hardcoded, which doesnt make much sense in an addon. Now I am looking for 2 possible ways to fix this.

Either I expose where the user can enter the file and directory

or

I find something like tkinters askopenfile.

Comment: If you have the variable exposed in a ui panel or set some kind of default in the addon preferences, you could set the subtype of the stringproperty to 'FILE_PATH' or 'DIR_PATH' as desired. [API](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html)
subtype (string) – Enumerator in [‘FILE_PATH’, ‘DIR_PATH’, ‘FILE_NAME’, ‘BYTE_STRING’, ‘PASSWORD’, ‘NONE’]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is an addon that you would need to complete with the code you want to execute for each STL you input, but it is a starting point.  It includes a panel with a button to invoke the operator, but you could do it with a menu entry, shortcut, or simply from the operator search menu instead.

It relies on the [`ImportHelper` class](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy_extras.io_utils.html#bpy_extras.io_utils.ImportHelper).  This class is not well documented, but the key feature is that it adds an `invoke` function to your class as well as a couple of members, mainly `filepath`, that it fills out when it calls the file browser from the `invoke` function.

Something that's hard to find in the documentation is that `ImportHelper` calls [`fileselect_add`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.WindowManager.html#bpy.types.WindowManager.fileselect_add) from [`invoke`](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/594f47ecd2d5367ca936cf6fc6ec8168c2b360d0/release/scripts/modules/bpy_extras/io_utils.py#L119) and it is `fileselect_add` that sets

> The string properties `filepath`, `filename`, `directory` and a `files` collection [...] when present in the [invoking] operator

It is the `files` collection that is used to iterate through the input files.

```py
bl_info = {
    "name" : "Import/Process STL files",
    "description" : "Import multiple STL files and process them",
    "author" : "Marty",
    "version" : (0, 0, 1),
    "blender" : (2, 80, 0),
    "location" : "View3D",
    "warning" : "",
    "support" : "COMMUNITY",
    "doc_url" : "",
    "category" : "3D View"
}

import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator
from bpy.types import Panel
from bpy.props import StringProperty, CollectionProperty
from bpy_extras.io_utils import ImportHelper
from pathlib import Path

class TLA_OT_stlhandler(Operator, ImportHelper):
    """ Import an STL and do things with it"""
    bl_idname = "import.stlhandler"
    bl_label = "Process STL"
    bl_options = {"REGISTER", "UNDO"}

    filter_glob: StringProperty(
        default='*.stl',
        options={'HIDDEN'}
    )

    files: CollectionProperty(type=bpy.types.PropertyGroup)

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.mode == "OBJECT"

    def execute(self, context):
        directory_path = Path(self.filepath).parent
        for file in self.files:
            bpy.ops.import_mesh.stl(filepath=str(directory_path / file.name))
            print(f'Do Your thing here')
        return {'FINISHED'}


class TLA_PT_sidebar(Panel):
    """Display Process STL"""
    bl_label = "STL"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "TLA"

    def draw(self, context):
        col = self.layout.column(align=True)
        prop = col.operator(TLA_OT_stlhandler.bl_idname)
 
classes = [
    TLA_OT_stlhandler,
    TLA_PT_sidebar,
]

def register():
    for c in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(c)


def unregister():
    for c in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(c)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this:

```
import bpy
import os

from bpy.props import StringProperty, BoolProperty
from bpy_extras.io_utils import ImportHelper
from bpy.types import Operator


class OT_TestOpenFilebrowser(Operator, ImportHelper):

    bl_idname = "test.open_filebrowser"
    bl_label = "Open the file browser (yay)"
    
    filter_glob: StringProperty(
        default='*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;*.tif;*.tiff;*.bmp',
        options={'HIDDEN'}
    )
    
    some_boolean: BoolProperty(
        name='Do a thing',
        description='Do a thing with the file you\'ve selected',
        default=True,
    )

    def execute(self, context):
        """Do something with the selected file(s)."""

        filename, extension = os.path.splitext(self.filepath)
        
        print('Selected file:', self.filepath)
        print('File name:', filename)
        print('File extension:', extension)
        print('Some Boolean:', self.some_boolean)
        
        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(OT_TestOpenFilebrowser)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OT_TestOpenFilebrowser)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.test.open_filebrowser('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

code from here:

https://sinestesia.co/blog/tutorials/using-blenders-filebrowser-with-python/